# Set background color for column

Tags: django, django-tables2

Is it possible to set background color of a column in a `django-tables2`? My rows consists of 2 different object data so I have to make `user` to simple distinguish between them.

For example by changing a css class of the column.

```
class AdminPairTable(tables.Table):
    reservation_1_destination_from = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.0.destination_from }}""")
    reservation_1_destination_to = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.0.destination_to }}""")
    reservation_1_date_departure = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.0.date_departure}}""")
    reservation_1_time_departure = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.0.time_departure}}""")
    reservation_1_specification = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.0.specification}}""")
    reservation_2_destination_from = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.1.destination_from }}""")
    reservation_2_destination_to = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{ record.1.destination_to }}""")
    reservation_2_date_arrival = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.1.date_arrival}}""")
    reservation_2_time_arrival = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.1.time_arrival}}""")
    reservation_2_specification = tables.TemplateColumn("""{{record.1.specification}}""")
    confirm_pair = tables.TemplateColumn("""<button class="btn btn-success">Zaradiť pár</button>""")
```

The only way which comes to my mind is to simply use `JQuery` but it's not a best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [column attributes](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html) while creating columns.

Not sure why you use the `TemplateColumn` to just render a value, just `Column` would work here too (except for `confirm_pair` of course).